# Как поменять местами два блока внутри нечетных строк?

Tags: php, css, вёрстка

Есть Блог, в котором идет перечисление статей.
Статьи располагаются 2 в ряд, то есть в Bootstrap это `.col-md-6`.
В блоке со статьей еще 2 блока: слева текст, а справа картинка.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы на четных рядах менялся порядок расположения текста и картинки (слева картинка, а справа текст).

Как возможно это реализовать? Через js я примерно делал такое, а вот можно ли это сделать на чистом PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему банальный css

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .row > div {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .row {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  img {
    float: left;
  }
  .row:nth-child(odd) img {
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: вот к чему приводит не полное знание css :) а я как раз только доделал цикл вывода row каждым двум блокам) Спасибо большое)